# Custom Iterable in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Can we have custom iterators in Spring Data Neo4j for Node Entities?
I have an existing code which has CustomHashCollection as an iterable. I want to convert the project to use Neo4j. Can I use the custom iterator as it is a private member in most of the NodeEntity classes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What is different with your Iterable?

As far as I remember there is no custom extensibility for iterable types, so far the JDK collection were good enough.

Comment: As per our code ,the base class is BaseObject ,which is not a NodeEntity.
we have a custom iterable namely CustomHashCollection as follows :
public class CustomHashCollection <T extends BaseObject> extends BaseObject implements Iterable<T> 
We have two Node Entities : Entity1 and Entity1 which have BaseObject as base class. Entity1 class has  CustomHashCollection <Entity2> as a member.Is it possible to use this custom iterable wit h minimum code changes.

Comment: No idea, perhaps you can setup a test project on github and raise a JIRA issue. This might be too specific, to be provided out of the box at any time soon.